# Using getWordUnderCursor to get words that contain apostrophes?

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

I'm using `monaco-editor` in an Electron application where users will be typing poetry. The language set for the editor is `plaintext`.

I'm running into an issue where if a user has typed a word with an ' (apostrophe) in it, `getWordAtPosition` won't return the full word. Depending on the cursor's position (which is what I pass into `getWordAtPosition`), it'll either return what's before the apostrophe, or what's after it.

For example, using a | (pipe) to represent the cursor's location, if the user has typed:

`couldn't|`

`getWordAtPosition` will return `t`

For `|couldn't`, it will return `couldn`.

What I want is for, regardless of cursor position, it will return `couldn't`.

What I've tried so far is supplying `wordSeparators` in the options when creating the editor that doesn't include the apostrophe (but is otherwise the default), but that hasn't helped.

Editor creation block:

```
editorInstance = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('editor'), {
            language: 'plaintext',
            wordSeparators: '`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:",.<>/?'
        });
```

Block using the `getWordAtPosition`:

```
fromEventPattern((handler: NodeEventHandler) => editorInstance.onDidChangeCursorPosition(handler))
            .pipe(
                map(() => {
                    const cursorPosition: IPosition = editorInstance.getPosition();

                    return editorInstance.getModel()
                        .getWordAtPosition(cursorPosition)
                        ?.word;
                }),
                filter((value: string) => !!value)
            );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a language configuration (either for a new language, or an existing one) and provide a `wordPattern` regex that will be used to match against words.

```
monaco.languages.setLanguageConfiguration('plaintext', {
    wordPattern: /'?\w[\w'-.]*[?!,;:"]*/
});


monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    language: 'plaintext',
});
```

Even though `plaintext` already exists as a language, this still works. I'm not sure if `setLanguageConfiguration` does any merging (I'd assume not?) so keep that in mind.

The regex in my code snippet isn't perfect, but it matches words like:

- Couldn't
- 'cause
- you?
- Hello

which was important for my use-case. Keep that in mind if you're a future searcher looking at this answer!